# How can I specify a Foreign Key relationship with EF Data Annotations and Fluent API?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the following database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Application] (
    [ApplicationId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [DataVersion] ROWVERSION,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Application] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ApplicationId] ASC)
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestAccount] (
    [TestAccountId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationId] INT,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [DataVersion] ROWVERSION,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TestAccount] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TestAccountId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT fk_AccountApplication FOREIGN KEY (ApplicationId) REFERENCES Application(ApplicationId)
);
```

My database has a lot more tables but I am just including these.

Can someone show me how I can use the EF Fluent API to model the fk_AccountApplication relationship?

How about doing this with data annotations. Is that easier to do? What's the most normal way for 
people to set up these relationships. With annotations or with the Fluent API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally find it easier to do it with data annotations, but I'm sure others will disagree with me (to each their own).

As far as data annotations goes, here's how you would do it:

Your Application object should include the following:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ApplicationID { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<TestAccount> TestAccounts { get; set; }
```

Then your TestAccount should include the following 2 properties:

```
[ForeignKey("Application")]
public int ApplicationID { get; set; }

public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
```

That should tell EF that there is a FK link between them